# nested apply outputting different structures for nearly identical inputs - what's going on here?

Tags: r, shiny, nested, apply

Context: I am trying to create an algorithm in Shiny which compares the HLA typing of a set of donors and recipients submitted by a user, but my code is failing due to NAs,

inputs:

```
  > recipss
      Recip_ID   HLA.A   HLA.B   HLA.C   HLA.DRB1   HLA.DQB1   HLA.DQA1
    1        1 A*02:01 B*44:02 C*03:02 DRB1*13:02 DQB1*03:01 DQA1*03:02
    2        2 A*02:05 B*44:03 C*02:02 DRB1*13:03 DQB1*02:02 DQA1*04:01

    > donorss
      Donor_ID   HLA.A   HLA.B   HLA.C   HLA.DRB1   HLA.DQB1   HLA.DQA1
    1       11 A*01:01 B*40:01 C*01:02 DRB1*12:01 DQB1*02:01 DQA1*01:01
    2       12 A*02:01 B*40:02 C*02:02 DRB1*12:02 DQB1*02:02 DQA1*01:02
```

code:

```
allele_mismatches_donors = apply(donorss,1,function(x){apply(recipss,1,function(y){x[which(x!=y)]})})
allele_mismatches_recips = apply(recipss,1,function(x){apply(donorss,1,function(y){x[which(x!=y)]})})
```

output:

```
> allele_mismatches_donors
$`1`
         1            2           
Donor_ID "11"         "11"        
HLA.A    "A*01:01"    "A*01:01"   
HLA.B    "B*40:01"    "B*40:01"   
HLA.C    "C*01:02"    "C*01:02"   
HLA.DRB1 "DRB1*12:01" "DRB1*12:01"
HLA.DQB1 "DQB1*02:01" "DQB1*02:01"
HLA.DQA1 "DQA1*01:01" "DQA1*01:01"

$`2`
$`2`$`1`
    Donor_ID        HLA.B        HLA.C     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQB1     HLA.DQA1 
        "12"    "B*40:02"    "C*02:02" "DRB1*12:02" "DQB1*02:02" "DQA1*01:02" 

$`2`$`2`
    Donor_ID        HLA.A        HLA.B     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQA1 
        "12"    "A*02:01"    "B*40:02" "DRB1*12:02" "DQA1*01:02" 


> allele_mismatches_recips
$`1`
$`1`$`1`
    Recip_ID        HLA.A        HLA.B        HLA.C     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQB1     HLA.DQA1 
         "1"    "A*02:01"    "B*44:02"    "C*03:02" "DRB1*13:02" "DQB1*03:01" "DQA1*03:02" 

$`1`$`2`
    Recip_ID        HLA.B        HLA.C     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQB1     HLA.DQA1 
         "1"    "B*44:02"    "C*03:02" "DRB1*13:02" "DQB1*03:01" "DQA1*03:02" 


$`2`
$`2`$`1`
    Recip_ID        HLA.A        HLA.B        HLA.C     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQB1     HLA.DQA1 
         "2"    "A*02:05"    "B*44:03"    "C*02:02" "DRB1*13:03" "DQB1*02:02" "DQA1*04:01" 

$`2`$`2`
    Recip_ID        HLA.A        HLA.B     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQA1 
         "2"    "A*02:05"    "B*44:03" "DRB1*13:03" "DQA1*04:01"
```

Problem:

```
> allele_mismatches_donors[[1]][[1]]
[1] "11"
> allele_mismatches_recips[[1]][[1]]
    Recip_ID        HLA.A        HLA.B        HLA.C     HLA.DRB1     HLA.DQB1     HLA.DQA1 
         "1"    "A*02:01"    "B*44:02"    "C*03:02" "DRB1*13:02" "DQB1*03:01" "DQA1*03:02"
```

The issue is that despite the variables being the exact same structure (I think) and containing the same type of data, the nested apply statement is outputting variables with non-identical structures which are not useful since I am trying to grab sub-elements using the same procedure on each variable.